# Bootstrap carousel not working (Its not sliding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<link href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="myCar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height: 100%;" >
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div id="myNewCar" class="carousel-inner" style="height: 100%; ">
       <div class="item active">
            <img src="~/assets/images/full-screen-image-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/assets/images/sidebar-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/assets/images/sidebar-5.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="~/assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am using bootstrap carousel in my asp.net mvc partial view but the images in the slider are not sliding it only displays the first image

Comment: Do you see any error in console (chrome developer tool)?

Comment: yes there are many errors in console

Comment: Which javascript code?

Comment: @Warda your carousel functions when you paste it into Bootply; if you have console errors that suggests either some other JS is conflicting or you haven't properly linked your CSS or JS.

Comment: If I have linked bootstrap js files or css files in my layout page in mvc do I need to paste it in the main View or partial views

Comment: Start by posting WHAT errors you get in console. Also, might as well tell us which BS version are you using since AFAIK carousel element changed bindings

Comment: Latest bs version 4.0.0

Comment: @SergeK. which javascript code?

Comment: Bootstrap needs popper.js as well. Load it after jQuery and before Bootstrap. Here is the relevant part from the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 changed `.item` to `.carousel-item`.  Update your HTML to reflect migration from BS3 to BS4 and your carousel will work as expected.  So change:

```
<div class="item active">
  <img src="~/assets/images/full-screen-image-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img src="~/assets/images/full-screen-image-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

And repeat for each iteration of your slides. For additional information on Bootstrap 4s Carousel component reference the documentation for the current version (4.0.0-beta2):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/